# Trouble parsing XML response from encrypted pinpad

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I'm currently trying to code support for an IDTech encrypted pinpad/card reader (HIDUSB device). Upon entry (either swiped or keyed), the device sends a response in XML which looks like the following:

```
<DvcMsg Ver="1.1"><Dvc App="SecureKey Demo Software" AppVer="1.0" DvcType="M130-IDTECH" DvcSN="54114600381" Entry="SWIPE"></Dvc><Card CEncode="0" ETrk1="ýÚ‹çMŒ·¯×Õ³a+.7ãN2†ÖcƒTWïX¿6`Eåq1Bk_–Ø‚ÑM€œœåê`S" ETrk2="ÓÙ|•QÎŠkÄn`å ¤óhîõRÐ3ÌÐ€{Rs¤Ì7MX¯nw" CDataKSN="P&ƒµ" Exp="0512" MskPAN="4444******4444" CHolder="PAYMENTECH" EFormat="4"></Card><Addr></Addr><Tran TranType="CREDIT"></Tran></DvcMsg>
```

I realize that the encrypted information in the ETrk1, ETrk2 and CDataKSN attributes contains invalid characters that would stop any XML parser in its tracks. Would there be a way to use a different character encoding to produce the hex equivalent of each character so that the XML can be parsed, or do I need to first manipulate the XML string to accomplish that?

Comment: What encoding did you use to get to this rendering? Chances are a small hardware device would use ASCII

Comment: @StenPetrov - The manufacturer's downloadable "demo" utility software produced this rendering. Interestingly enough, if I configure their utility to act as a keyboard wedge instead, the encrypted data shows up in perfectly legible hex.

Answer (score 0):

You might pre-process the string by just looking for illegal characters and replacing them with character codes (&#xxxx).  I would be worried about the encrypted blob some day containing a close quote though.  If that's a possibility I don't see a way around writing your own parser.

Another approach would be to not treat it as XML at all, and just look at it as mostly fixed text with some inserted variable sections.  So either run a regular expression, or if the fields are fixed length you could even just do SubString calls.  This is obviously more prone to breaking if the format changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I cannot assume the data is fixed length. After hearing back from the vendor, it's clear that what I need to do is parse the initial byte array to remove and store the encrypted info and then use an XML parser on the remaining data to get the rest.